# Proper Python Syntax and Semantics: if, else, pass

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, semantics

**Is there a preferred/proper style?** 
This:

```
def fx(Boolean):
    if Boolean:
        # Do stuff.
    else:
        pass
```

Or this:

```
def fx(Boolean):
    if Boolean:
        # Do stuff.
```

Is it preferred/proper to include `else: pass` if you don't want anything to happen? 
I've read [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and did not find anything concerning my question.

Comment: you don't need to give an `else` statement if you don't have anything to calculate with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never include `else: pass`. It's superfluous. Just omit the `else`; it's intentionally an optional keyword.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the `else` if there is no reason to add it. It will just confuse other people reading your code in the future (ie yourself a few months later).